# How to determine enode:// URLs of a Nethermind node?

Tags: url, ethereum, blockchain

I am creating an installer for blockchain software for a LAN. For every node, I need to edit `static-nodes.json` to have at least boot nodes for the current node.

The problem is that I didn't find any other way to determine a `enode://` URL (needed for `static-nodes.json`) of a node except to parse the logs.

Is there any other, better way?

If I cannot determine `enode://` URL in any other way, I want to pull request Nethermind with detemining `enode://` through JSON RPC. Is it a good idea from positions of security? Can it be done in a simpler way?

Comment: I found that the node ID can be determined using `admin_nodeInfo` method, but it is only available if the admin interface is enabled. I want to make it work in the case if the admin interface is not enabled, too.

Answer (score 1):

`enode` can be requested without enabling Admin module:

```bash
curl --data '{"method":"net_localEnode","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```